# Why is object property not setting correctly in loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I'm looping through an array and for each element 1) checking if it's a property in my object, 2) and if not, adding it to obj as prop with the val of it's index. Code is here in full as i'm not sure which part contains the error.

```
var repeat = function(arr) {

    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){

        const obj = {};

        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])) {
            return arr[i]
        } else {
            obj.arr[i] = i;
        }
    }
};
```

I'm getting the error "Cannot set property of '0' to undefined".
I did search similar questions and errors but didn't find an answer within the context of objects. Would appreciate insight as to this specific error and/or where my code is going wrong.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `obj[arr[i]] = i;`?

Comment: Doesn't ```obj[arr[i]] = i``` do the same thing as  ```obj.arr[i] = i```

Comment: no, not at all. `obj.arr[i]` is `(obj.arr)[i]`.

Comment: Just changed it to brackets instead of dot and the output is now undefined... Seems like setting obj property as arr[i] isn't working properly.

Comment: Well, as you declare `const obj = {};` on every iteration, getting `undefined` is not surprising - why would an empty object have any own properties? The function doesn't return anything, when the `if` never triggers.

Comment: Ahh. So declaring the obj outside the for loop should help this.

Comment: Yes, then the function should at least return something, if the array has duplicate entries. Still probably not exactly what you want though

Comment: After moving object declaration before for loop my code is now running properly. Thanks! Should've asked earlier. edit -yes it has duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to check the properties in a empty object.  `const obj = {};` You have to pass the object in to the function as  well. When adding the property to a object it should be like this obj["New Property"] = value. We can't add new values using .(dot) as we access values from objects.

```
var repeat = function(arr,obj) {

  var pObj = {}
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){

      if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])){
        pObj[arr[i]] = i
      }

    }

  const a = {...obj, ...pObj};
  return a;

};


var myarr= ["a","b","c","d"];
var myObj = {a:"Property A",b:"Property B"};
this.repeat(myarr,myObj)
```